# CMClock Swift Example

Tags: ios, swift, time, clock

I have two iOS devices physically separate from each other. I need them to perform a task at exactly the top of every minute and bottom of every minute (so every 30 seconds) and stay synchronized.

My initial approach was to calculate the time until the top of the next minute and set a timer until that time and then start my 30 second timer.

The problem was that the 30 second timer would drift and eventually be out of sync.

I discovered an [Apple API called CMClock](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coremedia/cmclock-u5q). I could not find an example but was wondering if anyone has used this API and if so could provide an example of how to keep two devices synchronized like I described?

Comment: I think that in the case of CMClock "devices" is referring to components on the iPhone such as cameras and not other iPhones.

Comment: To synchronise events across multiple devices you will need to use a network time source; look into SNTP.  Also you can't really set a timer for 30 seconds. On device timer dispatch isn't that accurate. Run your on device timer much faster (per second or even faster) and continually check the time.

Comment: Hey, did you implement the feature? I also want to synchronize 2 iPhones. Thanks!